# Fibonacci Problem #2 from Project Euler with PHP

Tags: php, fibonacci

The question goes like this:

> Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. By >starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:
>
> 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...
>
> By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, >find the sum of the even-valued terms.

And this is what I wrote in PHP

```
<?php
function fibo($first, $second, $limit){
  $next = $first + $second;
  if ($next % 2 ==0) {
    $array[]= "$next";
  }

  do 
  { 
    fibo($second,$next, $limit);
  } while ($next < $limit);

  $sum=array_sum($array[]);
  echo "$sum";
}
fibo(1,2,4000000);
?>
```

My code doesn't run though...can anyone help?

Comment: Does your code produce an error message or wrong output or nothing at all? Please specify what *doesn't run* means.

Comment: And please, for the love of god, format your code so we can read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `$sum=array_sum($array[]);` to `$sum=array_sum($array);` and see what it happens...

Also, when you have a problem, it's good to let the others know what kind of problem it is. Like the error message or something like that...

If by any chance there are no [errors reported, try to turn them on](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php).

EDIT:
I remember that when solving some Euler problems recursively I happened to have a problem where the page crashed. [This may happen due to some recursion limitations](http://bitdepth.wordpress.com/2010/05/16/php-recursion-causes-segmentation-fault/). I believe it's similar to your problem.

Comment: Thanks andre, you might be onto something because the code does cause a server error message on Chrome that says "HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request." There is no error message on Firefox though. I'll try to turn the error_reporting on and see what it says. Sorry about the formatting! My bad!

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple scope problem. You define `$array` in the function, you can't use it outside. Try using a global array:

```
function fibo($first, $second, $limit) {
  //...
  $GLOBALS[array[]] = $next; 
}
```

You will be able to use it outside.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand...do you mean i can't refer to $array outside of its function? But it was never referred to outside of its function?

Comment: @nubicurio Yes you did, like 13th line: `$sum=array_sum($array[]);`